# Error in LDAP, LDAP Result Code 2 \"Protocol Error\": 0000203D: LdapErr: DSID-0C091137, comment: Unknown extended request OID, data 0, v3839

Tags: go, ldap

What is the problem over here? I'm prioviding old, and new password. But somehow getting this problem while changing password.

- I'm using LDAP V3
  As request I'm using PasswordModifyRequest with oldPassword, newPassword and UserDN as domainLogin.
  Somehow always getting this issue. Is there a problem with my code or there should some specific setting on AD so my method can work?

  ```
    baseDN := "dc=" + strings.Replace(ldap.Domain, ".", ",dc=", -1)
    pass := ldap2.PasswordModifyRequest{
        UserIdentity: baseDN ,
        OldPassword:  OldPassword,
        NewPassword:  NewPassword,
    }

    // Send the ModifyRequest to the server
    res, err := li.Conn.PasswordModify(&pass)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error changing the password: %s\n", err)
        return err
    }
  ```

Comment: The first link if you search a popular Internet searching engine with the exact error message leads to [this](https://github.com/go-ldap/ldap/issues/106#issuecomment-342698860). FWIW, the search query was [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=0000203D%3A+LdapErr%3A+DSID-0C091137%2C+comment%3A+Unknown+extended+request+OID%2C+data+0%2C+v3839).

Comment: @kostix, if you look carefully. The error code that I posted here is leading me only to this topic. There is no topics with such issue code "LdapErr: DSID-0C091137".  The link you provided gives me solution for DSID-0C090D9A.

Comment: Given [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/570480/what-does-this-dsid-ldaperr-dsid-0c090aff-error-co) deciphering those "DSID" errors is going to be an interesting task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I decided to use Modify instead of ModifyPassword. The problem itself was about server properties and the version of AD. In my case, I provided more specific DN attributes and Control to use Modify.

```
controlTypes, err := getSupportedControl(li.Conn)
if err != nil {
   return err
}
        
control := []ldap2.Control{}
  for _, oid := range controlTypes {
     if oid == controlTypeLdapServerPolicyHints || oid == controlTypeLdapServerPolicyHintsDeprecated {
     control = append(control, &ldapControlServerPolicyHints{oid: oid})
       break
     }
}

err = li.Conn.Modify(passReqA)
if err != nil {
  return err
}
```